# How to do live delete data with react JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have some crud in my application. In `react` as we can know, we can do live crud concurrently with posting data to API. Like this:

```
const handleSubmit = async (someData:string) => {
        const result = await fetch('endpoint', {method:'POST', body:JSON.stringify(someData)})
        const data = await result.json()
        setDatas([...datas, data])
    }
```

And when we wanna delete them we can do this:

```
const handleDelete = async (id:string) => {
        const result = await fetch('endpoint', {method:'DELETE'})
        const data = await result.json()
        setDatas(datas.filter(data => data.id !== id))
}
```

But if we wanna add data and then delete it without refresh I can't delete the data, because I can't found id. How do I do it?

Comment: What do you mean with "I found id"?

Comment: @AKX I can't found. Forgive me. I typo.

Comment: your problem isn't clear. But you should fetch the records each time you add, update, or delete, in order to avoid "id not found" issue. I  mean, when you add a record, when the add call is successful, fetch the records to update the list with latest records

Comment: seems like your data in result.json() are not same as datas ... are you sure that format of both values is correct and that [...datas, data] is same array a s you are working with?

Comment: I ran in to same problem before, the best thing you can do is to make sure your data is same as datas. I assume after your page refreshed, it will automatically generated an id for the data, so you can delete it with an id